# Processing file in the users directory

Tags: php, file

I am writing a scripts that processes the .csv file. The script currently have to upload the csv file to the server in order to process it, and the user have to download the processed file which is a lot of work from a user.

My question is, is there a way to process files from the user's directory path without the user having to upload the file first? So the user will just browse to the file to be processed and the file will be save and processed in that path.

Thanks,
Sbo

Comment: You want to get access to user's computer? Forget it. Only way to achieve it is to use Java Applets with special permissions in php you need to upload it, it can be uploaded to temp directory but you need to still upload it.

Answer (score 0):

Then the only option you have is to do it client-side. To do it client-side you thus have to use a client-side technology like Flash or JavaScript. The latter is probably the better choice. The following URL explains how you can do a client-side file upload: http://igstan.ro/posts/2009-01-11-ajax-file-upload-with-pure-javascript.html

Comment: Yes, but not to the server. If you really want to access the file directly you have to use something like Flash: http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/08/20/reading-and-writing-local-files-in-flash-player-10/

Comment: When you use ajax + php it's server uploading. Flash may have features to access files on local storage but for sure ajax/php doesn't have such possiblities.

Comment: Thanks @ErikSchierboom, I get what you saying. I was thinking of options that I have, uploading the file first and processing it is not a problem, my problem is storing the processed file back to the original directory that was uploaded from. So is it maybe possible to store the file path of the uploaded file, then copy the processed file back to that directory using php, is that possible maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You want to get access to user's computer? Forget it.

Only way to achieve it is to use Java Applets with special permissions in php you need to upload it, it can be uploaded to temp directory but you need to still upload it.

**Java Applets** need to be signed and has certificate to be accepted by user. There is no other way I know to get access to user's files.

Check [this link](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/HowCanAnAppletReadFilesOnTheLocalFileSystem) as well